# ¿Cómo definir el estilo de un hipervínculo cuando está bajo el mouse, sin utilizar la etiqueta <style> o un archivo externo css, para email?

Tags: html, css

Mi intención es que al momento de que un hipervínculo se encuentre bajo el puntero del mouse este se ponga de color naranja y cambie el tamaño del background al 100% con 1px de grosor.

No puede ir en las etiquetas <.style.> o <.link.> debido a que he leído que algunos de los servidores de email principales como Gmail eliminan estas etiquetas o no las consideran.

Como se vería si se utilizara normalmente con la etiqueta <.sytle.>:

```
<style> a:hover {
    color: #ffa600;
    background-size: 100% 1px;
  }
</style>
```

En resumen la idea es pasar ese código adentro de la etiqueta <.a.> del hipervínculo, es decir, poner css en línea (inline):

`<a href="#" xxxx(supongo que aquí iría)>Enlace</a>`

**Gracias**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me he dado cuenta luego de seguir leyendo en internet, que hace años atrás fue que Gmail no consideraba las etiquetas <style.>  y sus reglas, sin embargo actualmente acepta ya muchas de las reglas y propiedades (sin embargo sigue sin aceptar algunas como background-size o background-position, si no me equivoco) de css.

Es decir, ahora si se produciría un cambio de color del texto del hipervínculo estando bajo el mouse si introduces el siguiente código css en la etiqueta head del html

```
<style>
     a:hover {color: orange}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

No es posible usar `:hover` cómo estilo *inline* porque es un pseudo-selector que únicamente tiene sentido para CSS, si se usa en una hoja de estilos.

Hay una respuesta más completa aquí en inglés https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033156/how-to-write-ahover-in-inline-css

---

### Edición:

**Respuesta corta:** no se puede.

...

`:hover` es una [`pseudo-clase`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes) y, mediante CSS, sólo tienen sentido dentro de una hoja de estilos. No hay ningún equivalente como [`inline-style`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/present/styles.html#h-14.2.2).

...

Ciertamente, si acaso es una opción, recuerda que agregar links a hojas de estilos externas de forma dinámica. Por ejemplo:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var link = document.createElement("link");
  link.setAttribute("rel","stylesheet");
  link.setAttribute("href","http://wherever.com/yourstylesheet.css");
  var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
  head.appendChild(link);
</script>

// asumiendo que existe una etiqueta <head>
```

---

*Respuesta traducida de https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033156/how-to-write-ahover-in-inline-css, siguiendo una recomendación en comentarios.*

Comment: Esta respuesta pinta para ser muy buena y aportar una excelente solución, te invito a que traduzcas el contenido de la solución y lo anexes aquí solo dejando los créditos al autor y así todos aprendemos. :)

Comment: Gracias por la recomendación @BetaM lo agregaré a la respuesta previa.

Answer (score 0):

Me temo que no se puede hacer, los selectores de pseudo-clases no se pueden configurar en la etiqueta html, tendrá que hacerlo en la página o en un archivo css.

Debo mencionar que técnicamente debe ser capaz de hacerlo de acuerdo a la especificación CSS, pero la mayoría de los navegadores no lo soporta.

También puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera y obtendrías resultados esperados imagino.

```html
<a href="#" onmouseover="this.style.color='red';" onmouseout="this.style.color='black';">Enlace</a>
```

Suerte.